# linq orderby with some condition

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sorting groups by active players...

In this case, the first group contains the biggest players inside:

```
List<Group> groups = tournament.Groups.OrderByDescending(o => o.Players.Count).ToList();
```

I have to add an filter that will count only active players, Something like this:

```
if (o.Players[index].Active == true)
    count Players[index] into o.Players.Count
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this :

```
List<Group> groups = tournament.Groups
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Players.Count(P => P.Active)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on active players only, you can hand over a predicate in the `Count` extension method:

```
List<Group> groups = tournament
                     .Groups
                     .OrderByDescending
                         (o => o.Players.Count(p => p.Active))
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to show in the result how many actual players are, not only sorting by them

```
var query = from g in tournament.Groups
            let activePlayers = g.Players.Count(p=>p.Active)

            orderby activePlayers descending
            select new {Group = g, ActivePlayers = activePlayers};
```